# Shortest way to do Linear Averaging in AVX

Tags: avx, avx2

I have an vector Inp = {A0, 0, A2, 0, A4, 0, A6, 0, ...};

my intrest is Out = {A0, mean(A0, A2), A2, mean(A2, A4), A4, mean(A4, A6), A6, ...};

- Inp & Out are float variables.
- Input length is always even. Hence, Out(end) = inp(end -1);

edit:

My implementation,

```
float *vecAPtr;
__m256 vecA;
__m256 vecB;
__m256 res1;
__m256 res2;
__m256 *AVXInp = (__m256*)Inp;
for(i = 0;i<inpLength;i = i+8)
{
  if( (inpLength - i) <= 8){
      //Normal C code
      Out[0] = Inp[0];
      Out[1] = (Inp[0]+Inp[2])/2;
      soon... (A simple for loop will take care of this part, not shown here)
   }
else
{
vecA = _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(*AVXInp, _mm256_set_epi32(1, 1, 6, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1) );
//vecA = [0 A2 0 A4 0 A6 0 0];

vecB = _mm256_permute_ps( *AVXInp, 0b10010001);
//vecB = [0 A0 0 A2 0 A4 0 A6];

vecAPtr = (float *)&vecA;
vecAPtr[7] = *( (float *)(AVXInp+1));
//vecA = [0 A2 0 A4 0 A6 0 A8];

res1 = _mm256_add_ps(vecA, vecB);
res2 = _mm256_mul_ps(res1, _mm256_set1_ps(0.5));
*AVXInp = _mm256_add_ps( *AVXInp, res2);
}
```

Is there any good version than this?.

Comment: What is the type of A0, A2, ... ?

Comment: @PaulR they are float variables..

Comment: Those `0` elements in the input are a waste of space and bandwidth; I assume you have some reason for them?  Just for the record, `vecAPtr[7] = *( (float *)(AVXInp+1));` is potentially terrible.  Better to just do another 32-byte unaligned load.  Although if you're lucky, the compiler will figure out that it can do it with `vbroadcastss` + `vblendps`.  If you're unlucky it will compile to much worse shuffling.

Comment: Probably better to do a load that gets all the elements you want and skips a zero, because introducing a zero can be much cheaper!

Answer (score 1):

I would first duplicate the even-indexed elements using `_mm256_moveldup_ps`, then load a vector starting at `Inp+1` and add it to that. Afterwards scale the odd elements by `0.5` (and the even elements by `1.0`):

```
void foo(float* out, float const* inp, size_t size){
    __m256 const scale = _mm256_setr_ps(1.f,.5f,1.f,.5f,1.f,.5f,1.f,.5f);

    for(size_t i=0; i<size-9; i+=8){
        __m256 even = _mm256_moveldup_ps(_mm256_loadu_ps(inp+i));
                                                // [a0, a0,      a2, a2,    ...]
        __m256 odd = _mm256_loadu_ps(inp+i+1);  // [ 0,    a2,    0,    a4, ...]
        __m256 sum = _mm256_add_ps(even,odd);   // [a0, a0+a2,   a2, a2+a4, ...]
        __m256 res = _mm256_mul_ps(scale, sum); // [a0,(a0+a2)/2,a2,(a2+a4)/2, ...]
        _mm256_storeu_ps(out+i, res);
    }
}
```

This does not handle the last elements. Also, it assumes that you are ok with returning `a0+0` where `a0` is expected (should only make a difference if `a0=-0`) and that `a0+a2` does not overflow.

Assuming the compiler fuses the load and the `_mm256_moveldup_ps`, the resulting [`vmovsldup`](https://uops.info/html-instr/VMOVSLDUP_YMM_M256.html) will not even require a shuffle operation, so every iteration just needs two loads, two arithmetics and one store (thus should have a throughput of 1 cycle, ignoring loop-overhead).